# How to get a DataVisualization.Charting Chart to show before points are added?

Tags: .net-4.0, mschart

How may I get a DataVisualization.Charting Chart to show its axes and gridlines before points are added? Currently the chart area is blank even if axes scale limits are set manually, and I can see no good reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Axis.Enabled properties to 'AxisEnabled.True' instead of 'AxisEnabled.Auto'

```
chartArea.AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea.AxisY.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
```